# Update query except specific columns

Tags: mysql

At the moment I have table like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | column5 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| n.v.t.  | n.v.t.  | n.v.t.  | n.v.t.  | n.v.t.  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| n.v.t.  | value   | n.v.t.  | value   | n.v.t.  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| n.v.t.  | n.v.t.  | n.v.t.  | n.v.t.  | n.v.t.  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Obviously this is a short version. At the moment I want a query that replaces all the 'n.v.t.' in all columns EXCEPT in column1 and column2. What I did is doing this with the standard UPDATE query. (SET column2 = 'replace_value' WHERE) etc.

Is there any way I can do this shorter? In terms of replacing all the 'n.v.t.' in all the columns except the specific ones?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as:

```
update table t
    set col3 = (case when col3 = 'n.v.t' then 'newvalue' else col3 end),
        col4 = (case when col4 = 'n.v.t' then 'newvalue' else col4 end),
        . . .
        coln = (case when coln = 'n.v.t' then 'newvalue' else coln end)
```

That is, use the replacement value if appropriate.  Otherwise, set the column to itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically get the columns with `SHOW COLUMNS FROM mydb.mytable;` and then, loop on these columns (except the ones you dont want) to build your update query